# XNA - Model doesnt display correctly

Tags: model, xna

I have to say I'm new to XNA and 3d game programming and dont know what im doing wrong. 
Problem is - i have to make a 3d scene asap so i want to use "ready to use" models.
However, after importing model and textures i get this effect:

[image]
I'm using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197293%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) example to display a model and [this](http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/free-nissan-350z-3d-model/588708) model.

And one more questions, any links to sites with xna compatible models would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance.

[image: Another one]

---

It seems every model I'm loading is acting differently, so i'm not sure but i think its caused by model file?? Is there an option to find 100% working models on the web? :|

Comment: What file format are the model files in? Are the transform matrices in the model being treated as column or row major? You may need to transpose the transform matrix

Comment: Models are in .fbx format, downloaded from turbosquid. I get your point with matrices transform, but how do you do that?

I thought that using models already made would be faster than creating my own, but now im lost..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that something in your models arent compatible with XNA. Probably some of the matrices, as Shirou_Wrath's answer states. In addition, XNA is kinda picka about how bones are set up. I don't remember completely, as I am a dev and use artists for all models, but I know that plug-and-play models rarely work unless they are spesifically made for XNA...

Also, Windows that are transparent need to be rendered after all other meshes (because of z-buffer), so rendering the cars will be a bit challenging in any case.

Comment: Ah i see, i'm out to work a little in blender then. Thanks for help!